Autocomplete suggestions for Redshift using SQLTools in VS Code
Is there any extension or a way to get autocomplete suggestions based on the connected database in vs code using sqltools or any other extension.
Currently I have sqltools and redshift drivers installed but it does not give any autocomplete suggestions for schema or table or column name like it does in data grip
Any leads?

I recommend datagrip

When in sqltools try 'ctrl+space' to see if it brings up the autocomplete suggestions.  Just a troubleshooting step to see if things are functioning properly.
